# Python Pandas Timeseries Sum Daily Column Data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to sum one of the columns in my dataframe based on day/month/year etc. I don't want to perform the aggregation on the other columns. As the dataframe will become shorter, I would like to use the minimum value from the other columns of the dataframe.

This is what I have, but it does not produce what I want. It only sums the first and last part and then gives me NaN values for the rest.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(points, data, junk), columns=['Dates', 'Data', 'Junk'])
df.set_index('Dates', inplace=True)
_add = {'Data': np.sum, 'Junk': np.min}
newdf = df.resample('D', how=_add)
```

Thanks

Comment: This code works for me ( I didn't know you could pass a dict to resample so thanks). Can you explain what you mean by 'first and last part' and provide a sample of the data?

Comment: Post raw data to reproduce your error

Comment: Can you also provide the output error you're receiving?